# How to put NULL in all cells of a matrix vector?

Tags: c++, vector

i'm trying to initialize all cells of a matrix with NULL values, but something is wrong here.
the code :

```
vector<vector<Distance*> > distanceMatrix;  
    for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
            distanceMatrix[i][j].push_back(NULL);
```

i bet it's something stupid, thanks for the help.

Comment: You could consider using boost::ptr_vector here - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: You can't safely use the indexing operator until after you've populated entries in the vector.  Change it to the safety-checked at() at you'll get some useful exceptions to help you fix your code.  Summarily, you need to push `vector<Distance*>` objects into distanceMatrix before you can push `Distance*`s into them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `std::vector` [reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/):

Vectors can be constructed with some values in them.

You may try:

```
vector<vector<Distance*> > distanceMatrix(7, vector<Distance*>(7, NULL));
```

---

Also, regarding your problem:

```
vector<vector<Distance*> > distanceMatrix;  
    for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
            distanceMatrix[i][j].push_back(NULL); //1
```

When you code first reach `//1`, `distanceMatrix[i]` resolves to `distanceMatrix[0]` but you did not call `distanceMatrix.push_back(vector<Distance*>())` so you are referring to a non initialized cell.

To correct code would have been:

```
vector<Distance*> vec;

for (int j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
  vec.push_back(NULL);

vector<vector<Distance*> > distanceMatrix;

for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
{
    distanceMatrix.push_back(vec);
}
```

Which is still far worse than my first suggestion.

Comment: is the NULL required for vector of pointers? What would default value be here?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: You're right, `NULL` is probably the default. However, I wanted to make it more explicit what parameters the constructor takes.

Comment: absolutely, just curious.  Never use vectors of ptrs myself.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix is empty to begin with, you need to `push_back` every value and every row, not depending on its position in the matrix:

```
vector<Distance*> row;
for(int j=0; j < 7; j++)
    row.push_back(NULL);

vector<vector<Distance*> > distanceMatrix; 
for(int i=0; i < 7; i++)
    distanceMatrix.push_back(row);
```

Comment: `push_back(new vector<Distance*>(row));` creates a dynamic vector that's only used momentarily for initialising distanceMatrix, then leaked... :-/.

Comment: This approach (if fixed) would imply a lot of row copying, bothersome for larger matrices than the 7x7 here

Comment: I was thinking "I'd better copy this", but meh. I fail ;)